# Calculating entropy of joint probability distribution observations of three variables in R

Tags: r, entropy

I have n observations of three variables, each variable being discrete with a different number of categories. For example, these are the first 10 observations:

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1) # 4 categories
v2 <- c(1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1) # 4 categories
v3 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1) # 2 categories
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(v1, v2, v3))
df
   v1 v2 v3
1   1  1  0
2   1  1  1
3   2  3  0
4   4  4  0
5   2  3  0
6   3  3  1
7   1  4  1
8   3  2  1
9   4  3  0
10  1  1  1
```

I am interested in quantifying the uniformity/diversity of the joint probability distribution of these three variables, in order to assess whether different combinations of their values are as likely as or not. If I understand correctly, Shannon entropy is an appropriate measure for that, but I am unsure how to calculate it from data such as the above.

So far I've tried using `table` to generate a count vector for all combinations of values, and then to pass it to the `entropy()` function from the `entropy` package:

```
freq_table <- as.data.frame(table(df))
freq_table
   v1 v2 v3 Freq
1   1  1  0    1
2   2  1  0    0
3   3  1  0    0
4   4  1  0    0
5   1  2  0    0
6   2  2  0    0
7   3  2  0    0
8   4  2  0    0
9   1  3  0    0
10  2  3  0    2
11  3  3  0    0
12  4  3  0    1
13  1  4  0    0
14  2  4  0    0
15  3  4  0    0
16  4  4  0    1
17  1  1  1    2
18  2  1  1    0
19  3  1  1    0
20  4  1  1    0
21  1  2  1    0
22  2  2  1    0
23  3  2  1    1
24  4  2  1    0
25  1  3  1    0
26  2  3  1    0
27  3  3  1    1
28  4  3  1    0
29  1  4  1    1
30  2  4  1    0
31  3  4  1    0
32  4  4  1    0

entropy::entropy(freq_table$Freq)
[1] 2.025326
```

However, I am unsure if this is the correct way to calculate this quantity. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "combinations" of these variables?  How are you combining them?  What joint probability distribution do you have in mind?

Comment: A combination is for example an event such as (v1=7, v2=2, v3=1), (9, 4, 0), (5, 4, 1), etc. I am interested in the probability of these events (estimated empirically from the data samples in the vectors) and in how equally probable they are. I apologize if I'm not clear enough.

Comment: You cannot compute those probabilities until you have information about the joint probability of all three variables.  That information is not inherent in having three vectors.

Comment: These vectors are simply ten observations. I have 10 observations of draws from this joint probability. Can't this be used to estimate it? I tried to clarify this in the question.

Comment: Your comments appear to contradict each other.  If you will allow combinations as described in your first comment, then you have only *marginal* data.  If you are drawing from the joint distribution, then it's misleading to permute the components of each vector independently, because that destroys the trivariate structure.  You need to determine what your vectors really mean and make that clear in your question.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited it again and added an attempt to do what I think I'm trying to do. I have n (or 10, for example) observations, each with 3 features, and I am trying to understand the entropy of these combinations.